# Selecting all elements in Array

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to select all Sheets that correspond to conditional in Array but the code don't work.

```
Dim arr() As String

y = Sheets.Count

cont = 1
arrInit = 0

For i = 1 To y

    Sheets(i).Activate
    If ActiveSheet.Range("a1") <> "" Then
        cont = cont + 1
        ReDim Preserve arr(1 To cont)
        arrInit = arrInit + 1
        Name = ActiveSheet.Name
        arr(arrInit) = Name
    End If

Next i
```

Comment: This code looks more like you are trying to build an array of worksheet names, not use an array to select all sheets, so your question does not make much sense. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Would be better to use `for each w in thisworkbook.worksheets` and use `w` instead of activating.  You will need to move this `cont = cont + 1` to after the `redim` or start at 0 also as you'll start at 2

Comment: Would be more efficient to `ReDim arr(1 To Sheets.Count)` before the loop and to `ReDim Preserve arr(1 To cont)` after the loop than having multiple `ReDim Preserve` inside the loop. The `ReDim Preserve` is pretty cost intensive.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav and peh thanks a lot, I really appreciate your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

### Write Worksheet Names to an Array

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SelectWorksheets()
    
    ' Either (safe), if you want to do it to the workbook containing this code
    ' (only one possible workbook) ...
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook
    ' ... or, if you want to do it to the active workbook,
    ' the workbook you're looking at (possibly one of many workbooks,
    ' could turn out to be the wrong one)...
    'Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ActiveWorkbook
    
    ' Note that there is a difference between the Sheets and the Worksheets
    ' collection. Since the condition is related to a cell, 'Worksheets' is
    ' the way to go.
    
    ' Write the number of worksheets to a variable.
    Dim swsCount As Long: swsCount = swb.Worksheets.Count
    ' Define an array of size of the number of worksheets. There can only
    ' end up less than or equal to swsCount worksheets in the array.
    Dim dwsNames() As String: ReDim dwsNames(1 To swsCount)
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet ' Worksheet
    Dim sValue As Variant ' Value
    Dim swsName As String ' Worksheet Name
    Dim dwsCount As Long ' New (Destination) Worksheets Count
    
    For Each sws In swb.Worksheets
        ' If you will allow error values in the cell or they are not possible,
        ' it is enough to use one If statement...
        'If Len(CStr(sws.Range("A1").Value)) > 0 Then
        ' ... instead of the following two, also making 'sValue' redundant.
        
        ' Write the cell value to a variant variable.
        sValue = sws.Range("A1").Value
        If Not IsError(sValue) Then ' not an error value
            If Len(CStr(sValue)) > 0 Then ' not blank
                dwsCount = dwsCount + 1
                swsName = sws.Name
                dwsNames(dwsCount) = swsName
            ' Else ' blank
            End If
        ' Else ' error value
        End If
    
    Next sws
    
    ' When all worksheets have blanks in the cell.
    If dwsCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No worksheets found.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' It is expected that not all of the worksheet names have been written
    ' to the array. Therefore the array has to be resized to the number
    ' of worksheet names written to it (dwsCount). Otherwise, an error
    ' will occur when you try selecting the worksheets from the array.
    If dwsCount < swsCount Then ' compare to the initial 'swsCount'.
        ReDim Preserve dwsNames(1 To dwsCount)
    End If
    
    ' Select
    swb.Worksheets(dwsNames).Select
    
    ' What else?
    
    ' 'msgbox' the names.
    MsgBox Join(dwsNames, vbLf), vbInformation, "Select Worksheets"
    
    ' Copy to a new workbook.
    'swb.Worksheets(dwsNames).Copy
    'Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ActiveWorkbook
    ' Continue...

End Sub
```

- Here's a quick fix to see where you went wrong (the major mistake being that the array was always one element too big e.g. you resized to 2 and wrote to 1).

```vb
Sub AQuickFix()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' ActiveWorkbook
    
    Dim arr() As String
    
    Dim y As Long: y = wb.Worksheets.Count
    Dim i As Long
    Dim aCount As Long
    Dim wsName As String
    
    For i = 1 To y
        With wb.Worksheets(i)
            If Len(CStr(.Range("A1"))) > 0 Then
                aCount = aCount + 1
                ReDim Preserve arr(1 To aCount)
                wsName = .Name
                arr(aCount) = wsName
            End If
        End With
    Next i

    If aCount = 0 Then Exit Sub  

    wb.Worksheets(arr).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, this help me a lot, I was really just trying 'sheets(Array())' and this is so much efficient.